# Render Airbnb google map markers with images

Tags: react-native

[image]

How do i customize my markers to bear many images as the airbnb google map interface does? and how would i upload the images to google maps without using story maps? Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read about `Marker` and `Callout` API (it depends on your need):

Follow official example for customizing them:

- CustomCallout: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/CustomCallout.js
- CustomMarker: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/CustomMarkers.js

If you don't like reading code, follow tutorial, eg:

https://codedaily.io/tutorials/9/Build-a-Map-with-Custom-Animated-Markers-and-Region-Focus-when-Content-is-Scrolled-in-React-Native

The above tut is not give you the same result, but it showed you how to customizing.

Comment: Hey...after trying to customize it i still cant find a work around in 'overflow: visible' in android... any suggestion of how i can go about it please